# MonoTouch, ZXing: Redirect to another ViewController after scan

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, zxing, xamarin

I'm using the ZXing MobileScanner lib with my xamarin project for iOS (MonoTouch).
I set up the scanning, it is working fine, reading my QRCode and having the correct result.
After reading the QRCode I want to show another ViewController. I set a property in the second Controller with the result from scanning and then want to show the controller.

The second view is not shown on screen. No errors, no feedback, simply not shown.
I guess, the MobileScanner builds up its own View (which can be seen in the source of the lib) and adds this to the NavigationController - and that this causes my Controller to stay "behind". Testing with simply redirecting to my controller on button clicks is working fine.
I also tried to "dispose" the view by calling scanner.Cancel(), but this results in

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x19a0c60> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

Here is my code, any help on how to display my view is appreciated.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.NavigationController);

        this.btnScan.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

            //Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            //We can customize the top and bottom text of the default overlay
            scanner.TopText = "Ticket vor den Scanner halten";
            scanner.BottomText = "Code wird automatisch eingelesen";

            //Start scanning
            scanner.Scan ().ContinueWith((t) => 
                                         {
                //Our scanning finished callback
                if (t.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion){
                    string msg = "";
                    ZXing.Result result = t.Result;

                    if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Text)) {

                        scanner.Cancel();

                        if(this.ticketScreen == null) {
                            this.ticketScreen = new TicketScreen();
                        } 

                        this.ticketScreen.ticketUrl = result.Text;
                        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.ticketScreen, true);

                    } else {
                        msg = "Code nicht erkannt!";
                        this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                            var av = new UIAlertView("Fehler!", msg, null, "OK", null);
                            av.Show();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });


        };


    }
```

Comment: If I put the opening of the second view into another buttons handler, it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I use ***this.InvokeOnMainThread(()*** and it works fine in my code. 
The solution for you is:

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

```
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.NavigationController);

    this.btnScan.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

        //Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
        //We can customize the top and bottom text of the default overlay
        scanner.TopText = "Ticket vor den Scanner halten";
        scanner.BottomText = "Code wird automatisch eingelesen";

        //Start scanning
        scanner.Scan ().ContinueWith((t) => 
                                     {
            //Our scanning finished callback
            if (t.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion){
                string msg = "";
                ZXing.Result result = t.Result;

                if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Text)) {

                    scanner.Cancel();

        this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            {
              if(this.ticketScreen == null) {
                    this.ticketScreen = new TicketScreen();
                } 

                this.ticketScreen.ticketUrl = result.Text;
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.ticketScreen, true);

        });



                } else {
                    msg = "Code nicht erkannt!";
                    this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        var av = new UIAlertView("Fehler!", msg, null, "OK", null);
                        av.Show();
                    });
                }
            }
        });


    };


}
```

Comment: Invoking on the main thread still causes the warning, but it does push the controller.